# Passing words to a function

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to pass words to a function that will be checked with words in a seperate file. It only passes the last word created from the first file and not each word. So I think how it should work is as soon as it creates a word it should pass that word to the function then check it and return the results, but I'm confused as to how. If the word matches a word in the second file it should print the word then a 0 or if it doesn't match a word then print 1.

```
import sys

argc = len(sys.argv)

cmdlength = argc - 1

if cmdlength != 2:
    print ("Usage error, expected 2 args got " + str(cmdlength))
    exit()
else:
    word = ""
    with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as fh: 
        while True:
            ch=fh.read(1)
            if not ch:
                print(word)
                print("End of file")
                break
            if ch == ' ':
                print(word)
                word = ''
            else:
                word += ch

        def check_word(word):
            count = 0
            count2 = 0
            with open(sys.argv[2],"r") as fh2:
                lines = fh2.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                if word in line:
                   print(word , ": " , "0")
                   count += 1
                else:
                    print(word, ": " , "1")
                    count += 1
        check_word(word)
```

Comment: What does it do currently?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `check_word` function, you are doing it once after the `while` loop ends, for that reason only the last word is passed to the function. You should call the function after each word is armed, in your case, when `ch == ' '`:

```
if ch == ' ':
    print(word)
    check_word(word)
    word = ''
```